# How to upload an image with flask and store in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb, flask-wtforms

A previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812940/display-image-attach-from-couchdb-in-html-via-flask-python/40839716#40839716) asks how to retrieve at attachment from couchdb and display it in a flask application.

This question asks how to perform the opposite, i.e. how can an image be uploaded using flask and saved as a couchdb attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example from [WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file):

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_wtf.file import FileField

class PhotoForm(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField('Your photo')

@app.route('/upload/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def upload():
    form = PhotoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = secure_filename(form.photo.data.filename)
        form.photo.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
    else:
        filename = None
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form, filename=filename)
```

Take a look at the [FileField api docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).  There you have a stream method giving you access to the uploaded data.  Instead of using the save method as in the example you can access the bytes from the stream, base64 encode it and save as an attachment in couchdb, e.g. Using [put_attachment](https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html?highlight=attachment#couchdb.client.Database.put_attachment).  Alternatively, the FileStorage api docs suggest you can use `read()` to retrieve the data.